# VBA Activesheet

Tags: vba, excel, date

I'm trying to make a monthly evaluation.
  I would like to read the sheet name, and then transform it into a date.
The individual worksheets have the names January, February, etc.
When I wanted to issue 0116, 0216, 0316 and get this save.

```
tabellenblatt = ActiveSheet.Name
```

Comment: I don't get your qestion exactly. You want to take the month e.g. January from the worksheetname and change it to 0116 (month.year)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your problem is that you don't know how to transform month name into number ( but as string).  Here is a solution (to be completed - I am not going to do all your work :)

```
Function getMonth(mname As String) As String
'returns month number as string, from month name. Eg: returns "02" for "Feb"
    Dim a()
    Dim i As Integer
    a = Array("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "...")
    i = Application.Match(mname, a, False)
    getMonth = Format$(i, "00")
End Function
```